# Is there a template for curriculum vitae in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, templates

Is there a template for curriculum vitae in Microsoft Word 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT101043371033.aspx) ? you can even found [here](http://www.cvtips.com/resumes-and-cvs/cv-example.html). .. you can see thousands of result by searching "cv templates microsoft word" ! good luck

Comment: +1 Beat me by 5 seconds. I posted the exact same link.